# В цикле while не выполняет условие if

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if, tuple

Крестики-нолики. 
Cверх всех функций есть возможные комбинации внутри списка **`p`**.  
`list_of_y` и `list_of_z` сохраняет список пользовательского ввода, но после не выполняет сравнение и поиск в списке, и не показывает, кто победил.

```py
**Все выигрышные комбинации:**(их получил через итертулс)
p=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 5, 6), (4, 6, 5), (5, 4, 6), (5, 6, 4), (6, 4, 5), (6, 5, 4), (7, 8, 9), (7, 9, 8), (8, 7, 9), (8, 9, 7), (9, 7, 8), (9, 8, 7), (7, 4, 1), (7, 1, 4), (4, 7, 1), (4, 1, 7), (1, 7, 4), (1, 4, 7), (8, 5, 2), (8, 2, 5), (5, 8, 2), (5, 2, 8), (2, 8, 5), (2, 5, 8), (9, 6, 3), (9, 3, 6), (6, 9, 3), (6, 3, 9), (3, 9, 6), (3, 6, 9), (7, 5, 3), (7, 3, 5), (5, 7, 3), (5, 3, 7), (3, 7, 5), (3, 5, 7), (9, 5, 1), (9, 1, 5), (5, 9, 1), (5, 1, 9), (1, 9, 5), (1, 5, 9), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
win = False
desk=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list_of_y=list() **список на основе пользовательского ввода**
list_of_z=list() **тоже , для другого игрока**

def drow(desk):
    print(desk[0:3]), print(desk[3:6]), print(desk[6:10])

def in_put(desk, win, p):   
    while not win:
        y=int(input("Куда поставить _x_?    : "))
        if desk[y-1]==y:
            desk[y-1]='x'
            list_of_y.append(y)
            print(desk[0:3]), print(desk[3:6]), print(desk[6:10])
            if len(list_of_y)>=3 and list_of_y in p:
            // (то, что я назвал сравнением и поиском в спике)
                print('"*"12, "Победил:", "*"*15, "\n\n","*"*15, "X","*"*15')
            else:
                pass
            z=int(input("Куда поставить _о_?     : "))
            desk[z-1]==z
            desk[z-1]='o'
            list_of_z.append(z)
            print(desk[0:3]), print(desk[3:6]), print(desk[6:10])
            if len(list_of_z)>=3:
                if list_of_z in p:
                // (то, что я назвал сравнением и поиском в списке)//                 
                      print('"*"*12, "Победил:", "*"*15, "\n\n","*"*15, "O","*"*15')
            
drow(desk)
in_put(desk, win, p)
```

Comment: 1. А что храниться в переменной 'p'?
2. И не потерян ли if тут? desk[z-1]==z # тут if? 3. Не вижу где переменной 'win' присваивают значение True. Это должно быть где то здесь?
4. После сообщения о победе стоит поставить 'break'

Comment: И чему же равна длина вашего списка `p`? Учитывая, что списки типа `list_of_y` вы не сортируете, а ходы можно делать в любом порядке, то, так, на вскидку, мне представляется, что там должно лежать 48 вариантов из трёх позиций, затем 1152 варианта из четырёх позиций, и, наконец, 9600 вариантов из пяти позиций. :)

Comment: Так. Сейчас долью код, чтобы убрать лишние вопросы (может и не лишние, я дно здесь) Я, в целом, уловил основную мысль, но очень-очень прошу ответить ток на вопрос, что там происходит в части, где  if len(list_of_y)>=3 and list_of_y in p: (как он может игнорировать и продолжать цикл или что там python делает, мне кажется это будет моим инсайтом, если я разберусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам еще придется хорошенько потрудиться.

Сделайте ваш объект  **`p`** - списком списков, а не список кортежей.

```
#**Все выигрышные комбинации:**(их получил через итертулс)
#p=[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (4, 5, 6), (4, 6, 5), (5, 4, 6), (5, 6, 4), (6, 4, 5), (6, 5, 4), (7, 8, 9), (7, 9, 8), (8, 7, 9), (8, 9, 7), (9, 7, 8), (9, 8, 7), (7, 4, 1), (7, 1, 4), (4, 7, 1), (4, 1, 7), (1, 7, 4), (1, 4, 7), (8, 5, 2), (8, 2, 5), (5, 8, 2), (5, 2, 8), (2, 8, 5), (2, 5, 8), (9, 6, 3), (9, 3, 6), (6, 9, 3), (6, 3, 9), (3, 9, 6), (3, 6, 9), (7, 5, 3), (7, 3, 5), (5, 7, 3), (5, 3, 7), (3, 7, 5), (3, 5, 7), (9, 5, 1), (9, 1, 5), (5, 9, 1), (5, 1, 9), (1, 9, 5), (1, 5, 9), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
p = [
     [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1], 
     [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [5, 4, 6], [5, 6, 4], [6, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4], 
     [7, 8, 9], [7, 9, 8], [8, 7, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [9, 8, 7], 
     [7, 4, 1], [7, 1, 4], [4, 7, 1], [4, 1, 7], [1, 7, 4], [1, 4, 7], 
     [8, 5, 2], [8, 2, 5], [5, 8, 2], [5, 2, 8], [2, 8, 5], [2, 5, 8], 
     [9, 6, 3], [9, 3, 6], [6, 9, 3], [6, 3, 9], [3, 9, 6], [3, 6, 9], 
     [7, 5, 3], [7, 3, 5], [5, 7, 3], [5, 3, 7], [3, 7, 5], [3, 5, 7], 
     [9, 5, 1], [9, 1, 5], [5, 9, 1], [5, 1, 9], [1, 9, 5], [1, 5, 9], 
     [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]
    ]


win = False
desk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list_of_y = list() #**список на основе пользовательского ввода**
list_of_z = list() #**тоже , для другого игрока**

def drow(desk):
    print('[ {} , {} , {} ]'.format(*desk[0:3])) 
    print('[ {} , {} , {} ]'.format(*desk[3:6])) 
    print('[ {} , {} , {} ]'.format(*desk[6:10]))

def in_put(desk, win, p):   
    while not win:
        y = int(input("Куда поставить _x_?    : "))
        if desk[y-1] == y:
            desk[y-1] = 'x'
            list_of_y.append(y)
            
#            print(desk[0:3]), print(desk[3:6]), print(desk[6:10])
            drow(desk)
            
            if len(list_of_y) >= 3 and list_of_y in p:
#            // (то, что я назвал сравнением и поиском в спике)
#                print('"*"12, "Победил:", "*"*15, "\n\n","*"*15, "X","*"*15')
                print('\nПобедил: "X"')
                return                                                 # +++
            else:
                pass
            z = int(input("Куда поставить _о_?     : "))
            desk[z-1] == z
            desk[z-1] = 'o'
            list_of_z.append(z)
            
#            print(desk[0:3]), print(desk[3:6]), print(desk[6:10])
            drow(desk)
            
            if len(list_of_z) >= 3:
                if list_of_z in p:
#                // (то, что я назвал сравнением и поиском в списке)//                 
                      print('\nПобедил: "O"')
                      return                                            # +++
                      
                      
                      
drow(desk)
in_put(desk, win, p)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
print([2,5,8] in p)
```

выдаст False. поэтому if-ы не отрабатывают.

Плюс, как заметил т-щ GrAnd, еще есть выигрышные комбинации состоящие из >=4 значений.
Не подскажу правильный алгоритм проверки выигрыша, но думаю найти не сложно. Удачи :)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).